# How to do the MySQL query for the following scenario?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables.

```
1. inventory - inventory_subcat_id as fk
2. inventory_cat
3. inventory_subcat - cat_id as fk
```

Now if I want to get inventories from a certain category, how to build my query?

Note: My inventory table only has subcat_id in it which is a fk for id in inventory_subcat table. inventory_subcat has cat_id which is a fk for id in inventory_cat.

Lets say,

```
inventory_cat has
{id=> 1, name=> A}
{id=> 2, name=> B}

inventory_subcat has
{id=> 1, cat_id=> 1, name=> subcatA}
{id=> 2, cat_id=> 1, name=> subcatB}
{id=> 3, cat_id=> 2, name=> subcatC}
```

so now subcatA and subcatB both belong to cat named A.

```
now if i have inventory
{id=> 1, subcat_id=> 1, name=> inv1}
{id=> 2, subcat_id=> 2, name=> inv2}
{id=> 3, subcat_id=> 3, name=> inv3}
```

Now, if I want to get all the inventory items from cat A, that is

```
{id=> 1, subcat_id=> 1, name=> inv1}
{id=> 2, subcat_id=> 2, name=> inv2}
```

because of both subcat_id 1 and 2 bellongs to cat_id 1.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add to the table inventory a foreign key to inventory_cat as well.

As for your current layout, in order to get from inventory to inventory_cat, you just need to make two joins: one between inventory and inventory_subcat (because you need inventory_subcat.cat_id), and then one between inventory_subcat and inventory_cat (because you need inventory_cat.name).

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM inventory_cat c
 INNER JOIN inventory_subcat s ON s.cat_id = c.id
 INNER JOIN inventory i        ON i.subcat_id = s.id
 WHERE c.name = 'A';
```

After you join you tables together, your data would look like this:

```
[c.id] [c.name] [s.id] [s.cat_id] [s.name]   [i.id] [i.subcat_id] [i.name]
1      A        1      1          subcatA    1      1             inv1
1      A        2      1          subcatB    2      2             inv2
2      B        3      2          subcatC    3      3             inv3
```

At this point, you select only the rows for category 'A' (WHERE c.name = 'A'), and show only the columns of inventory (SELECT i.*)